Next JS 14 - MySQL connection load Schema
So, I have a NextJS 14 install. I have a MySQL connection setup and a schema.sql file that I load. Currently, I load the schema.sql on the route app/dashboard, but I don't want to execute my SQL code on every page call:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clients (....);

How should I go about only loading the schema once the NodeJS server has run(and not on every client request)? To my understanding, using the server.js file is not recommended. I don't see another solution, however.

Database schema is generated during installation (initial or patch) if the software is packaged one, or using your route-to-live devops pipeline if the app is developed in house. Application code is not the right place to do this.

@Shadow Can you explain why it is bad practice? I feel that a webapplication that might be installed on some machines, might benefit from it being integrated into the application.
So what would the best practice be to go doing this? Would i create a shell-script, or a separate "npm run setup_database" command or something like that?

It depends whether your product is intended for distribution (multiple instances) or only used in house. For the former, you need to create installation scripts for main install and subsequent patches. If this is an in-house development, then the database should be setup by your devops pipeline, preferably one that uses some kind of a version control system for database schema as well. This could be done through database migrations or database schema version control tools, like liquibase.
